# Haproxy not loading site correctly

Tags: haproxy

I have a standard Haproxy config. The site works without Haproxy in front. I've put a test site on 2 server and Haproxy on separate server in front.

```
frontend site
    mode http
    bind *:80
    default_backend webservers
    option forwardfor
    http-request set-header Forwarded for=%[src]

backend webservers
    balance roundrobin
    server webserver1 95.85.xx.xx:80
    server webserver2 45.77.xx.xx:80
```

The site is loading but asset files from subdirectories give errors getting retrieved ([screenshot](https://image.frl/i/ph53c56ijofa3rol.png) of browser inspect).

Any idea what is causing this issue?

Comment: Capture logs from HAProxy.  They should reveal that one or both of your backends are returning this error because files are missing or the incoming `Host` header doesn't match what the backend expects.  Not enough information provided to speculate further.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed it. I forgot the round ribbon requests were calling both servers randomly on assets when loading one session. One server apparently failed on deploying files and missed a few.

Comment: Please mark this as 'correct' so the question drops off the unanswered list.